# Swift ios - read key=value text file into nsdictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have various text files where each line contains string-key=string-value

I can read the file into string (or maybe an array), go over line by line and split into key/value pairs myself, however, I was wondering if I was missing some built-in or easier "swift" way of doing this (new to swift)

I could not find this question discussed before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core concept still relies upon `componentsSeparatedByString` but you canmake it appear more "Swifty" by using a higher-order function like `reduce`:

```
let fileContent = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: "/path/to/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let result = fileContent.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
                .reduce([String: String]()) { (var dict, line) in
                    let components = line.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
                    dict[components[0]] = components[1]
                    return dict
                }
```

What it does is: split the file's content by line, start with an empty `[String: String]`, loop through each line, split it and assign the key-value to the dictionary.

Comment: Since this is a question exploring "Swifty" ways of performing a task, I just thought I'd mention that you could use the string's `characters` property and call `split`, as an alternative to using `componentsSeparatedByString` i.e. `fileContent.characters.split("\n").reduce...` etc. You would need to construct new `String`s in the closure. I'll leave an answer if that's not clear!